# Como puedo hacer que el formulario venga con ciertos campos ocultos, pero cuando yo escoja una opción del select se muestre el un campo

Tags: php, javascript

Como puedo  hacer que el formulario venga con ciertos campos ocultos, pero cuando yo escoja una opción del select  se muestre el un campo, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Me hago explicar mejor: tengo un campo ***select***  llamado categoría en el cual hay 3 categorías alimento, aseo y vacación, lo que quiero lograr es que cuando escoja vacunación se des oculten los campos de ***indicaciones*** y ***contraindicaciones***, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

para ocultar elementos por defecto puedes agregarle la etiqueta:

```
style="display: none"
```

y Cuando quieres que el elemento se muestre al cambiar un elemento `select` sera:

### en vanilla:

```
document.addEventListener('input', function (event,elem) {
    if (event.target.id !== 'wizard') return;
    /*  Aqui va tu Codigo para remover el stilo */
    elem.style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```

### en jquery:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  $("element").show()
});
```